# How many tickets can be sold so that all punctual passengers get a seat?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

> Assume on average $7\%$ of passengers holding a valid ticket don't
>   show up or are too late to their flight. Now, we want to sell more
>   tickets than there are seats. How many tickets can be sold for a plane
>   with $240$ seats to assure with $99\%$ probability that all punctual
>   passengers with a ticket also get a seat?

Suppose $X$ is the number of people who show up. Then $X \sim Bin(n, 0.93)$.

We now want to find $n$ where $\mathbb{P}(X_n \leq 240) \geq 0.99.$

We should probably use the normal approximation to the binomial distribution.

From the Limit Theorem of de Moivre and Laplace we know that:

$\mathbb{P}(X_n \leq 240) \approx \Phi(\frac{240-0.93 \cdot n}{\sqrt{n\cdot 0.93 \cdot 0.07}})$.

How can I now find $n$?

Comment: You are looking for the 99th quantile of a distribution. Thus you have two choices. Either look it up in a quantile table or compute it with software.

Comment: @GradaGukovic There is no smart way to calculate it by hand?

Comment: No. Unless you know the quantile table by hard.

Comment: You know $n$ has to be between $240$ and $\lceil 240/0.93\rceil = 259$ so you can just test in that range.